# How to specialize a small part in a large template function in compile time

Tags: c++, templates

The problem is the following: I have a rather large template function (about 200 lines) that must run very efficiently. However, in a particular line I need to specialize the function depending on the type. I do not know what is the best efficent way to solve this. Here are some ideas:

1. I can obviously use `if (typeid(T) == typeid(some_type))`, but I have doubts that this is done in compile time since comparing `typeid`'s is not `constexpr`. Let me know if I am wrong.
2. I can move these lines to a `constexpr static` function in the classes used as template types. However, this moves the code in a place I do not want it to be.
3. I can duplicate the 200 lines. OK, let's not do that...

I am missing any better way of doing it? How would you do this? I am using C++14.

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using ? You can use if constexpr for compile time conditional code in C++17

Comment: "specialize the function depending on the type" overloading?

Comment: @Clonk just edited it. I'm using C++14. How would you do it in C++17?

Comment: you can also create generic lambda function if you are using c++14, that will handle that specific part of larger function

Comment: *"large template function (about 200 lines)"*. Create sub-functions, so you can specialize only a small part without copy the common part.

Comment: @xception, AFAIK, nowadays `inline` is more about ODR than code inlining. Functions that are not marked as `inline` can also be inlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the syntax you're looking for

```
/* pass parameter by reference in case you wanna change it */
inline void do_something(some_type &x/* , other parameters that any of the functions might need */)
{
    ++x; /* example, you can do anything */
}

inline void do_something(some_other_type &y/* , other parameters that any of the functions might need */)
{
    y = y * y; /* example, you can do anything */
}

template<typename T> void very_large_function(T t)
{
    // ... common code ...
    do_something(t);
    // ... more common code ...
}
```

if your `if` statements also had an `else` you can do this instead

```
// final else
template<typename T>
inline void do_something(T &t) {
    t = t * 2; // example
}

inline void do_something(some_type &x)
{
    ++x; // example
}

inline void do_something(some_other_type &y)
{
    y = y * y; // example
}

template<typename T> void very_large_function(T t)
{
    // ... common code ...
    do_something(t);
    // ... more common code ...
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `do_something` be also templated ? Otherwise you lose `very_large_function`genericity

Comment: @Clonk no, each instantiation of `very_large_function` does overload resolution independently

Comment: @Clonk I believe the `if` was there exactly because he wanted to do something different with the types, depends a lot on his code I guess, it's hard to give the best solution without some initial code in this case

Comment: @Caleth yes but If I call `very_large_function` with a type that is not overloaded by `do_something` it won't compile. Therefore I'm limited in the type T by the type implemented by `do_something`

Comment: @Clonk the point is to have a set of overloads of `do_something`. One of them might be a catch-all template. It depends how `very_large_function` is used

Comment: I added the `else` situation to the response to include that case

Comment: You don't need specializations for `do_something`. `inline void do_something(some_type &x)` should work.

Comment: Say what? Specialization and overloading are different mechanisms. Both functions and function templates can participate in the overload resolution. This article can be helpful: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: thanks, it's just that I've always done specializations for some reason, must have been some misunderstanding in my mind

Comment: thanks, accidentally removed when I removed the specialization